# is that the .htaccess rewrite mode don't work with a ~ symbol in url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

is that the .htaccess rewrite mode don't work with a ~ symbol in url?

The scenario is that i have used the .htaccess rewrite in some folders in the server and it works fine. But with a ~ symbol it seems not working and i get a 404 error message.
ie. ~ symbol is used on the username of a FTP account, pointing to the server.

the actual .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ pages.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*).html/$ pages.php?slug=$1
```

this works fine with the url

```
www.abcdxyz.com/something/pages/index.html
```

But the prob is in the other way

```
www.server.com/~ftpaccount/pages/index.html
```

here the account is not pointed to any domain name thats why i used a ~ symbol to view the files from the server. And i use a linux server.

P.S. pardon me if i'm not clear with the question.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no `ftpaccount` user? Where is this ht access file? is there one in the `ftpaccount` public_html directory? is mod_userdir loaded?

Comment: yes the .htaccess file is in the public_html directory and mod_userdir is also fine. but till not working. i mean, is the ~ symbol had some thing to do with the .htaccess file. tanku for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "B" flag at end of your RewriteRule example your #1 rule becomes

> RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ pages.php?slug=$1 [B]

What it does is:
Escape non-alphanumeric characters before applying the transformation